# introduction textbook to the Laplacian on a circle bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, fibre-bundles, laplacian, principal-bundles

I am looking for an introduction to spectral theory of $\Delta$ on a circle bundle over a compact M. Is there an analog of Selberg trace formula?